# Android studio Default activity not found error

Tags: android

[image]

I have been writing code and as my emulator doesn't work I connect my android device to test app. But recently it is giving me

> "Error running 'app': Default Activity not found"

I am attaching the image of my `activity.xml` I can't see the view of my design

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of package issue. You need to give complete package name along with Activity. In your scenario, **.** means referring to current package. In your case your current package is **com.example.brian**. For the time being android studio is looking for **MainActivity**  inside **com.example.brian**. This is contrary to fact because your activity is inside another package (one more hierarchy down) and that **myfirstapp**.
Hope this helps you some clear understanding regarding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a folder named `java`. Inside `java` you have a package called `com.example.brian`, and inside this, you have another package called `myfirstapp`.
In your `activity_main.xml` file, you have written `tools:context=".MainActivity"`.
This means that this `xml` layout should be used in an `Activity` called `.MainActivity`. However, this activity does not exists. Why? Because the dot is referred to `com.example.brian`, but your `MainActivity` is saved inside `myfirstapp` package.

**Solution 1**:

You should write

```
tools:context=".myfirstapp.MainActivity"
```

I suppose that the same is happening inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file. 
Instead of referring to `.MainAcitivity` you should write `.myfirstapp.MainActivity`.

**Solution 2**:

Move your `MainActivity` file to `com.example.brian` package.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more as I am new to the android studio. Just let me know how can I view my app in design view